# Design Pattern: How to handle different version of class which has different properties?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

My C# app reads json file which changes over time (weekly or monthly) and it has to support all the versions. For example,

```
Version 1
{firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe"}

Version 2
{firstname:"Tony", lastname:"Doe", address:{line1:"Xavier", line2:"California"}}

Version 3
{firstname:"Adam", lastname:"Wood", address:{line1:"13 House", line2:"Texas", pincode: 12345}}
```

My C# class which deserialise the json looks like below,

```
// Version 1
public class DetailsV1: IBase
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
}

// Version 2
public class DetailsV2: IBase
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private AddressV1 address;
}

// Version 3
public class DetailsV3: IBase
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private AddressV2 address;
}
```

From my brief search in Google, it says Strategy pattern is a good choice for this kind of problem. So, I created a context class like below,

```
public class Context
{
    private IBase details;
    private int version;

    public Context(int version, string path)
    {
        this.version = version;
        // TODO The version should be parsed from the file
        if (version == 1)
        {
            this.details = new DetailsV1(path);
        }
        else if (version == 2)
        {
            this.details = new DetailsV2(path);
        }
        else if (version == 3)
        {
            this.details = new DetailsV3(path);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    // To avoid unnecessary boilerplate, I believe the below functions should return only primitive types
    public int getPinCode()
    {
        if (version == 1)
        {
            throw new NotAvailableInThisVersionException();
        }
        if (version == 2)
        {
            throw new NotAvailableInThisVersionException();
        }
        if (version == 3)
        {
            var address = (this.details as DetailsV1).address;
            var pc = (address as AddressV2).pincode;
            return pc;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my queries,

- Is this correct design pattern or is there any other better design pattern for my usecase? My versions can grow upto 400+ and thus, my class also grows. I feel this if/else will look ugly (and error prone?).
- If this is the correct design pattern, Is it correct to cast the address in getPinCode or this has to be handled inside the DetailsV3 class (i.e) DetailsV3 should have a method called getPinCode?
- If this is the correct design pattern, then I presume these methods should provide only primitive types (or types I am sure going to be static forever). Am I right?

Comment: Maybe you can use strategy pattern and then switch case instead If/Else?

Comment: *"versions can grow upto 400+ and thus, my class also grows"* - Hence, you just answered yourself that "strategy" may not be the answer because it will require finding 400 implementations. This is too much coding

Comment: Find a way to normalize the data so that you don’t have 400 implementations of the same sort of thing

Comment: It looks like some fields are optionally added

Comment: @DanielA.White yes. It is added and/or modified and/or replaced.

Comment: @DanielA.White could you share an explanation of normalisation? Is it grouping of fields in a class say Nameclass, AddressClass and so on? If yes, I still see there will be a new version of some class. For example, if middle name is added, then there is going to be a new version of NameClass

Comment: Just add it to the existing class.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, patterns are general guidance. you should modify them as you wish using the available framework tools

for example

```cs
public interface IUserDetailsHandler
{
    int GetPinCode();
    // more here
}

public class UserDetailsHandlerV1 : IUserDetailsHandler
{
    private DetailsV1 _details;

    public UserDetailsHandlerV1(string file)
    {
         // _details loaded here from file
    }

    public int GetPinCode()
    {
         int pinCode = // retrieve or set to default value, whatever
         return pinCode
    }
}

// more handler classes here
```

Now you need to somehow decide which class to load - `IUserDetailsHandler handler = Something.GetHandler`.  You can use 'naming convention' and reflection approach to find handler from version.

Lets say All your handlers

1. Implement IUserDetailsHandler and
2. Have naming pattern `"UserDetailsHandlerV" + i`

```cs
public static IUserDetailsHandler CreateHadler(int version, string file)
{
    const string namePrefix = "UserDetailsHandlerV";

    Type handlerType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(c => typeof(IUserDetailsHandler).IsAssignableFrom(c) && 
                             !c.IsInterface && 
                             !c.IsAbstract &&
                              c.Name.Equals(namePrefix + version));
    
    IUserDetailsHandler handler = null; 
    if (handlerType != null)    
        handler = Activator.CreateInstance(handler, file); // with ctor parameter

    return handler;

}

// ^^^ This should save you 300 if().
```

Again, there are **many** situations where traditional patterns need to be adjusted to **your** reality. NOTE: you might inherit classes when only one property added. But then again, 400 versions... you might want to look into some dynamic JSON stuff using Newtonsoft, ExpandoObject, etc. And develop some sort of logic that knows how to search through hierarchies. The reflection code above can remove need to `if/switch`. Moreover, your file itself can contain the version and you can derive the model from there. And more. Your issue doesn't seem in implementing a specific pattern but rather, how to remove need to have so many models. Potencially, you can have 1 model for ALL properties but the difference will be made in handler. Each handler might select and combine differently certain properties but no others.

Disclaimer - code is not tested

Comment: Thanks for answer. If I use interface like this, then whenever a new method is added, I have to fix all the handler versions? Or am I missing something? Moreover, here there is going to be 400 Details class and 400 handler class. Am I right?

Comment: And thanks for sharing ExpandoObject. I didn’t know it existed and I feel it could reduce the if/else mess. I am only concerned will it cause any quality issues (I don’t know yet but if something is dynamic, I am scared :) ). I will continue reading about it.

Comment: @Selva I might not thought that you're going to be adding new functionality as time goes. if you can define interface ahead, this is best. I thought, you can define that, only the form of input would be different. If this is not the case you can substitute interface with a base class and make methods virtual. In this case, adding new method will not break all classes. Make it virtual. **next** The number of `handler` and `detail` classes could be different. For example, your detail might have same format but you have 3 different handlers that turn it into different output

Comment: You can also think about having one class and using extensions. I still feel that your case is good for some reflection-based calls. For example, make your class process any code and register all the models and handlers. Use that registry to invoke any extension with any detail model. for example this method gets data in same manner for many mixes of handler/detail -  `public static int GetSomethingV1(this IHandler h, IDetail d)`.